# Java application blocking security Java 8 Update 45

Tags: java, security, java-8, japplet, java-security

My applet application is blocked with java security.

- I tried to adding the site to trusted sites , but it didn't worked
- The Medium security were removed from Java 8 Update 45

I would like to know how to remove the security?
Also I wondering what makes my application unsafe and how to make it safe?

Comment: *"what makes my application unsafe and how to make it safe?"* Does it have the required attributes in the manifest?  See [JAR File Manifest Attributes for Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/manifest.html).

Answer (score 0):

Be certain that you have manifest entries such as this sample (adjust for your unique circumstances):

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: https://app.mycompany.com/applicationfolder
Application-Name: HelloWorld
```

You may apply the manifest through something along the lines of:

```
"%JDK_HOME%\bin\jar.exe" ufm ..\dist\application.jar manifest.txt
```